# How can I smooth a triangle fan?

Tags: modeling

As a picture often speaks better than words, here are the two images of my problem. I'm trying to get a smooth render on this object. I tried many options but no way I always have these artifacts. Is it possible to have a smooth rendering with a convex surface? [image]

[image]

Here what I'm trying to model
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Subsurf Modifier doesn't work well with Triangles.

Ideal topology consists of mainly quads (faces with four vertices) and each vertex is connected with exactly four edges.

I created the following quarter sphere by smooth subdiving a cube (edit mode: <kbd>w</kbd> > <kbd>u</kbd>), shaped it to a sphere (edit mode: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd>) and deleted the excess vertices.

[image: spherically curved surface with quads]

---

EDIT: After requests and additional info in the question, I will provide a step by step workflow.

1. Create a cube <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > <kbd>C</kbd>, then go into edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>). Make sure the pivot stays in the center of the cube.
   [image: cube in edit mode]
2. Do a smooth *subdivision operation* three times. (<kbd>W</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>)
   [image: smooth subdivided cube]
3. Select and delete the unnecessary vertices.
   [image: select vertices on a spherical cube]
4. Select the outer edge loop (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + rightbuttonclick) and scale it to zero along the Y - axis. (<kbd>S</kbd> > <kbd>Y</kbd> > <kbd>0</kbd>). Make sure to enable proportional editing for this step, so the topology stays even.
   [image: scale to zero along y]
5. With the edge loop still selected, do the *to sphere* operation.(<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> > <kbd>1</kbd> > <kbd>Enter</kbd>)
   [image: edge loop to sphere]
6. Select all vertices <kbd>A</kbd>, enable 2D Cursor as Pivot <kbd>.</kbd> and do the *to sphere* operation.(<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> > <kbd>1</kbd> > <kbd>Enter</kbd>), the last edge loop will still be on two axis.
   [image: curved surface with straight end]
7. Delete the additional vertices, then select the lower edge loop.
   [image]
8. Extrude, scale according to the reference, insert edge loop to make the edges clearer.
   [image]

Comment: Thanks Leander but I  tried unsuccessfully your method. I can't medel your shape. You use the "subdivide option first"?

Comment: Thanks Leander but I tried unsuccessfully your method. I can't model your shape. You use the "subdivide option first"?

Comment: I updated my post. I finally understood how to transform a cube into a sphere but the geometry doesn't match to what I'm trying to model (cf image).

Comment: @Grobby I extended my answer with a step by step explanation.

Comment: Thanks Leander for your full tutorial. I don't know why (I enable the proportional editing) but at the step 4 only the edge loop turn into a circle shape and I don't have the protuberance on the back like you.

Comment: Double check the settings of the scale operation (on the left in the Tool Tab). My Falloff is set to Linear and the size to 1.33

Comment: That was the reason but also because i  was selecting the edges of the edge loop not the vertices so that the deformation was not based on the vertices,