# How do I get rid of these ridges?

Tags: modeling

I am trying to create a curved surface at the bottom of the object but when I use the subdivision surface modifier in conjunction with an edge crease, these ridges appear on that edge as shown in the screenshot. Any ways to prevent this?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the model. I might be able to solve this. It's pretty common. But before that please check things on youtube. This happens quiet often when creases are used with subdivision. So the answer is already there.

Comment: 3 steps to try: 1 M merge by distance, with all selected. 2 Alt-N  (Normals) > recalculate outside. 3. H Hide the big face, check for internal faces and delete.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23596/smooth-shaded-model-has-odd-shading/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1684/what-is-the-technical-difference-between-an-ngon-and-a-bunch-of-triangles/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/186849/why-are-my-objects-shadows-so-janky https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118128/how-to-fix-ugly-lines-in-my-mesh/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63903/how-can-i-smooth-a-triangle-fan